# React build files giving net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden) in Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, deployment, gunicorn

I'm using nginx and gunicorn to deploy my Django+React web application. When I start the nginx services and try to access the application in the browser, in the browser's console I'm getting an error saying

> GET http://server_ip/static/css/2.2546a949.chunk.css net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)

Below is what my nginx conf file looks like

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name server_ip;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}

location /static/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias react_build_folder_location;
}
}
```

Also, I've given read and execute permission to the static files still not able to fix the issue! Can anyone please help me. Kindly excuse if its a repeated question.

Comment: If you open that url in your local environment, using a browser, what do you get?

Comment: @Hackerman using django's runserver?

Comment: Also add the value of `react_build_folder_location` and make sure that the nginx service has read permission over that folder

Comment: Thank you @Hackerman I gave read execute permission to my project. Now the static files are serving. Thank you again.

Comment: Glad to help Aashay! 